# Ubuntu 15.04 dual monitors lose window

Tags: multiple-monitors, 15.04

When i'm on work i use 2 monitors.
When ubuntu is locks on timeout, or suspend and then work on internal laptop display (at home) some windows can't show, because of incorrect window coordinates.

I found a workaround - wmctrl -i -r  -e 0,200,200,500,500
can help to move window to a visible position.

My questios is - how can completly solve problem with switch between 1 and  2 monitors, without unvisible windows.

too many words, may be need a screenshots ?)

Comment: Seems like your screen setting/resolution is not updated. What is the output of xrandr when windows are hidden?

Comment: Output of command is there: http://pastebin.com/EQsnYVED

Problem window is this:
0x04603155  0 4005 124  1335 648  bazz-pc 1 vs 2 (/home/bazz/PycharmProjects/untitled)

Comment: Which is your internal screen?  the left or right one?

Comment: internal screen is right.